# How To Get Any Blob Property in Azure using PowerShell 7

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, powershell-7.0

I am using the below code to access and retrieve blob properties in Azure. I want to make this function generic so that I can call it with any 'property' name instead of as it is hard coded below to retrieve only the "IsServerEncrypted" property:

```
function GetBlobProperty   {
    Param(   
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $blobProperty, # <<<<<=I want to retrieve any property
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $storageAccountName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $storageAccountKey,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $containerName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $blobName
    )    
    $ctx = GetStorageContext $storageAccountName $storageAccountKey
    $Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx
    $retValue = ""

    ForEach ($Blob in $Blobs){
        #Write-Host $Blob.Name  
        if($Blob.Name.IndexOf($blobName) -ge 0)
        {
            Write-Host $Blob.Name
            $retValue = $Blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.IsServerEncrypted #I want to pass $blobProperty here
            break;
        }


    }
    return $retValue
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just do `$Blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.$blobProperty` and check if the property exists(not null).

```bsh
function Get-BlobProperty {
    Param(   
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $blobProperty,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $storageAccountName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $storageAccountKey,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $containerName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $blobName
    )    
    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
    $Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx
    $retValue = $null

    ForEach ($Blob in $Blobs){
        #Write-Host $Blob.Name  
        if($Blob.Name.IndexOf($blobName) -ge 0)
        {
            Write-Host $Blob.Name
            if ($null -ne $Blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.$blobProperty) {
                $retValue = $Blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.$blobProperty
                break;
            }
        }


    }
    return $retValue
}
```

Although I prefer using [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7) to check if the property exists:

```bsh
function Get-BlobProperty   {
    Param(   
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $blobProperty,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $storageAccountName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $storageAccountKey,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $containerName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $blobName
    )    
    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
    $Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx
    $retValue = $null

    ForEach ($Blob in $Blobs){
        #Write-Host $Blob.Name  
        if($Blob.Name.IndexOf($blobName) -ge 0)
        {
            Write-Host $Blob.Name

            if (Get-Member -InputObject $Blob.ICloudBlob.Properties -Name $blobProperty -MemberType Property) {
                $retValue = $Blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.$blobProperty
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $retValue
}
```